# Is there any difference between git repository and git repository ported using gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit, repository

what's the difference between a git repository and a git repository ported by gerrit and placed under gerrit? Can i just bypass the gerrit and use the gerrit'ed repository as normal git repo? BTW, gerrit is good but we try to keep things a bit simpler for now in term of code review. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the gerrit'ed repository as a normal git repo.  Most users still go through Gerrit, even if they aren't using code review for a particular repository, because it handles authentication, permissions, etc.

But Gerrit fully supports having the repository change on the filesystem without going through the Gerrit ssh or http/https servers, and this won't cause any issues.